# How to post $1.69 amount to Canadian QuickBooks Online Tax Inclusive Invoice with QBXML

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, qbxml

I cannot seem to post an item to a Canadian QuickBooks Online Tax Inclusive Invoice with QBXML for an amount of $1.69.  The tax rate involved is 13%.  Per [How do i push a bill with taxes included](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D5G000004Dk6wCKAR/) response, I am dividing the desired amount of $1.69 by 1.13, sending that amount and the resulting invoice shows $1.70.  I tried different amounts in the request and discovered that sending $1.495 results in $1.70 on the invoice and sending $1.494 results in $1.68 on the invoice.  Any ideas how I could get $1.69 to show up on the Tax Inclusive invoice amount when that is what it should be?

Here is a copy of the request that results in $1.68.  Change the Amount tag to 1.495 and it results in $1.70.

Edit: I took it out a few more decimal places and discovered that 1.4949999 results in $1.68 and 1.49499999 results in $1.70.  Still no $1.69.

Edit: $1.69 isn't so special.  I recreated the process in a spreadsheet with a 13% tax rate starting at $1.50 and incrementing by $0.01.  About every eighth or ninth value is one that cannot be added to one of these invoices.

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <Line>
    <Description>Guest Book</Description>
    <Amount>1.494</Amount>
    <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
    <SalesItemLineDetail>
      <ItemRef>7</ItemRef>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <TaxCodeRef>5</TaxCodeRef>
      <ServiceDate>2017-03-08</ServiceDate>
    </SalesItemLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <CustomerRef>2</CustomerRef>
  <GlobalTaxCalculation>TaxInclusive</GlobalTaxCalculation>
</Invoice>
```